# rendered attribute of h:outputLabel not working properly when called from a4j:commandButton click

Tags: ajax, jsf

Please help me solving this issue in JSF which one change of the bean.displayInd from false to true the outputLabel is not rendering.
On click of the commandButton , filterRequest method is called which sets the value of displayInd to true.But the value is still coming as false and rowCountLabel is not working??Hardcoding the value of rendered attribute to true or false its working.SO is the issue in render call from a4j:commandButton?

```
 <a4j:commandButton value="Filter" action="#{bean.filterRequest}" render="rowCountLabel"/>

 <h:outputLabel id="rowCountLabel" value="#{bean.rowCount}"
                rendered="#{bean.displayInd}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping `h:outputLabel` in `a4j:outputPanel` and rendering it will solve the problem.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Filter" action="#{bean.filterRequest}" render="rowCountLabel"/>

<a4j:outputPanel id="rowCountLabel">
     <h:outputLabel value="#{bean.rowCount}" rendered="#{bean.displayInd}"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```